# Pandas map calendar to index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a full-year hourly series, that we may call "calendar":

```
from pandas import date_range, Series

calendar = Series(
    index=date_range("2006-01-01", "2007-01-01", freq="H", closed="left", tz="utc"),
    data=range(365 * 24)
)
```

[image]

Now I have a new index, which is another hourly series, but starting and ending at arbitrary datetimes:

```
index = date_range("2019-01-01", "2020-10-02", freq="H", tz="utc")
```

I would like to create a new series `result` that has the same index as `index` and, for each month-day-hour combination, it takes the value from the corresponding month-day-hour in the `calendar`.

I could iterate to have a working solution like so, with a `try-except` just to ignore February 29th:

```
result = Series(index=index, dtype="float")
for timestamp in result.index:
    try:
        calendar_timestamp = timestamp.replace(year=2006)
    except:
        continue
    result.loc[timestamp] = calendar.loc[calendar_timestamp]
```

[image]

This however, is very inefficient, so does anybody know how to do it better? With better I mean specially faster (CPU-time-wise).

Constraints/notes:

- No Numba, nor Cython, just CPython and Pandas/NumPy
- It is fine to leave February 29th with NaN values, since that day is not represented in the calendar
- We can always assume that the index is properly sorted and has no gaps (the same applies to the calendar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try extracting the combination as string and map:

```
cal1 = pd.Series(calendar.values,
                 index=calendar.index.strftime('%m%d%H'))

result = index.to_series().dt.strftime('%m%d%H').map(cal1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Definitely much faster and cleaner. I will also try converting the m-d-H to an integer, which may slightly increase performance. Allow me to wait a little bit before accepting, since I am looking for any other possible answer someone comes up with. :-)

Comment: I simplified the question maybe too much, since I am working with DataFrames and not Series. I would like to copy rows from the calendar into the new index (i.e.: the resulting DataFrame has the same columns as the calendar). It seems I am unable to modify your solution to make it work with DataFrames. Is there an easy way or should I ask a new question?

Comment: Nothing wrong, if that is the best way. I thought maybe there was a way without explicitly iterating over the multiple columns, since I want to use all the columns from the calendar (no selection/exclusion). Is iterating the best way?

Comment: There's a merge option.

Comment: Is it easy to explain in a comment? Otherwise I may just ask a new question just for that. :-)

Comment: @Peque If possible, another question with sample data is best.